# Ideal system for an encryption scheme

Tags: encryption, provable-security, security-definition

What is the ideal system for an encryption scheme? For a pseudorandom permutation the ideal one is a random permutation, for a pseudorandom function the ideal one is a random function. For an encryption scheme do we have a well known application describing an ideal system for an encryption? Maybe the one-time pad?

Comment: An OTP is a good example. [Take a look at this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9023/5231), particularly the definition it contains

Comment: possible duplicate of [definition and meaning of semantic security](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9017/definition-and-meaning-of-semantic-security)

Comment: If you are concerned about idealization of crypto protocols (of which encryption is a special case), you could look up references about the **Universal Composability** framework (UC framework).

Comment: Thank you user7423, which references I should look ?

Comment: You could start with Canetti's paper: http://eprint.iacr.org/2000/067